# Understanding errors from ordinal logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, ordinal

I am using `MASS::polr` to run ordinal logistic regressions, but I am getting a lot of errors that I am hoping people can enlighten me about.

First if I run this the function fails to find starting values:

```
MASS::polr(as.ordered(cyl)~mpg+gear,mtcars)
```

So if I specify starting values, I get an error from `optim` stating 'non-finite value supplied by optim':

```
MASS::polr(as.ordered(cyl)~mpg+gear,mtcars,start=c(1,1,1,1))
```

After reading some R-help, and previous stack overflow questions about this, the response is usually that there is something wrong with the data i.e. the response variable has a category with relatively few values, but in this instance I don't see anything wrong with `mtcars`.

Any guidance on how to diagnose, and deal with issues in data that will impact `MASS::polr` would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Going on a scavenger hunt through `?polr`, the starting values are to be specified *"in the format `c(coefficients, zeta)`"*. Looking lower, we see that `zeta` is *"the intercepts for the class boundaries."*. In the **Details** section, we can see that the zeta values must be ordered:

> `zeta_0 = -Inf < zeta_1 < ... < zeta_K = Inf`

([sic], as that presumably should be a `< Inf` at the end.) 
So you need the second zeta value to be greater than the first. This works, for example:

```
MASS::polr(as.ordered(cyl) ~ mpg + gear, mtcars, start = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
```